# My IPv4 Address automatically changes

Tags: windows-8.1, ipv4

I have Windows 8.1,
For some reasons I need forward ports for my computer. (you may know that computer's IPv4 Address is necessary for it).
But my computer's IPv4 address automatically changes after some days, so I have to port forward again everyday :(
This is very annoying for me.
Please help me to make my IPv4 Constant.
I am on a Home Internet Network.

Comment: Set a static ip in W8 http://portforward.com/networking/static-ip-windows-8.htm

Comment: Aye. That and make sure that static IP in not in the DHCP pool (though most DHCP server seem to check these days).  Alternative: give the PC's MAC a fixed IP in the DHCP server.

Comment: Yeah, i have not seen ip collisions in years.

Comment: @Moab,Will it make my IPv4 Address constant?

Comment: @HumzaDogar You're referring to a *private* IP address right? Not public?

Comment: @nKn, Yeah. Its private ip

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

You can either set yourself a manually configured IP address, or have your router reserve an IP address for your MAC address.

The simpler option is the first one, which is explained in [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings)

**Manually configured IP Address**

1. Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Control Panel. In the search box, type adapter, and then, under Network and Sharing Center, click View network connections.
2. Right-click the connection that you want to change, and then click Properties.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
3. Click the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, click ... Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)...
4. To specify an IP address, click Use the following IP address, and then, in the IP address, Subnet mask, and Default gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.

You can use the same IP you have as a dynamically allocated one, however, it may be allocated to another machine, so it's best to use one later in the pool (or if you know the size of the pool, outside of it entirely). EG, if your IP is currently `192.168.0.5`, use something more like `192.168.0.105`.

**Address Reservation** - preferable if you're connecting to multiple networks often and don't want to change from a manually configured IP to dynamic frequently

It depends on your make and model where you will find the settings. It will be within your DHCP settings, for mine it's under 'Address Reservation' but this may vary:

[image: Address Reservation]

To find your MAC address, go to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `cmd`, type `ipconfig /all` and hit enter. You'll get all your network adapters back, look for the one you use (EG, WiFi adapter) and find the `Physical address`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Add this to your routers DHCP server address reservation. You may need to release and renew your IP, or disconnect and reconnect.

Comment: If you do not know what the current values for these settings are, then go to [start] [run] `cmd` `ipconfig`